How to pass container ID to elastic search
we have launched our .net core application to containers. Our application currently sends logs to directly to elastic search. At the moment we are following ECS standard and would like to pass container.id but I am not entirely sure how to achieve this.
I know we can wrap it in a scope but that seems quite tedious to do that for every call. I am wondering if there's a better way to achieve this, possibly in a middleware or program.cs or appsettings?
using (_logger.BeginScope("{ContainerId}", ContainerId))
{
  _logger.LogDebug("This is the containerId.", ContainerId);
}


Do you mean to add containerId as a extend property for every log?

{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  private readonly ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> _logger;

  public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
  {
      _next = next;
      _logger = logger;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
      // Retrieve the container ID here (you need to implement this logic)
      string containerId = GetContainerIdFromRequest(context);

      using (_logger.BeginScope("{ContainerId}", containerId))
      {
          // Log the container ID for each request
          _logger.LogInformation("Container ID: {ContainerId}", containerId);

          await _next(context);
      }
  }
}

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();
  // Other middleware registrations
}```


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
